# Grouping including non grouped field using Linq/Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list which has data

```
list1 [{actId: 1, dt:'10/5/2015', hr:3}, {actId: 1, dt:'10/5/2015', hr:5},
        {actId: 3, dt:'10/4/2015', hr:3}, {actId: 4, dt:'10/6/2015', hr:1},
        {actId: 4, dt:'10/6/2015', hr:8}, {actId: 1, dt:'10/2/2015', hr:3}]
```

I am using a Linq query to group the data

```
 var dat= list1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(t=> new{t.actId, t.dt})
     .Select(x=> new 
            {
               tId=x.Key.techId,
               dat=x.Key.dt,
               thrs=x.Sum(y=>y.hr)
            });
```

This works and gives me result but gives me the results grouping both "actId" and "dt" while I want to just group them by "actId". If I change the query to

```
     var dat= list1.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(t=> new{t.actId})
     .Select(x=> new 
            {
               tId=x.Key.techId,
               dat=x.dt,
               thrs=x.Sum(y=>y.hr)
            });
```

I get intellisense error for x.dt saying "Cant Resolve Symbol "dt"

Please let me know how to change the query so I can include x.dt in it without grouping by it. 
So output should look like

```
 [ {actId:1, [{dt: 10/5/2015, hr:8}, {dt: 10/2/2015, hr:38}]},
  {actId: 3, [{dt: 10/4/2015, hr:3}]},
   {actId: 4 [{dt: 10/6/2015 hr: 9}]}]
```

Thanks

Comment: Basically what you're asking for doesn't make sense, but please add your exact required output and we'll see...

Comment: `actId: 1` has multiple values for `dt`.  Which one do you expect to have in your output?  First?  Latest?  "Random"? A concatenation?  That will determine how to formulate the query?

Comment: I added the desired output. Basically to group by actId then display for each date the total hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because there isn't a single 'dt', there is a group of them, this will return them all as a group for you:

```
var dat=list1.AsEnumerable()
     .GroupBy(t=> t.actId)
     .Select(x=> new 
            {
               actId=x.Key,
               dat=x.Select(x=>new { x.dt,x.hr}).ToList()
            });
```

This is as close as I can get to your output.  It'll look like:

```
 [ {actId:1, dat:[{dt: 10/5/2015, hr:8}, {dt: 10/2/2015, hr:38}]},
  {actId: 3, dat:[{dt: 10/4/2015, hr:3}]},
   {actId: 4, dat:[{dt: 10/6/2015 hr: 9}]}]
```

Comment: It is close. Please see the desired output I just added.

Comment: @J.Davidson Updated answer.